# handling divs with only values

Tags: jquery, click

I have something like this

```
<div class="button" value="15">Button</div>
<div class="button" value="16">Button</div>
<div class="button" value="17">Button</div>
<div class="button" value="18">Button</div>

<div class="click_me" value="16">CLICK HERE</div>
```

I need something like this

```
-- pseudocode --
$('body').on('click','click_me',function(){
    $('.button').withValue($('.click_me').val()).somethingHappens();
});
```

So when I click on certian element with certian value, other element with some class with this value activates/changes/function start.

Comment: and what have you tried? We are here to help develop.

Comment: instead of value you can have `data attribute` or `id`s

Comment: See the attribute selectors. http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatenate the target value directly into the selector:

```
$(".button[value='" + $('.click_me').attr('value') + "']").somethingHappens();
```

Comment: I think this was the best answer, but still it depends upon the OP's choice :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var val = $('.click_me').attr('value');
$('.button').filter(function(){
    return val === this.getAttribute('value');
}).somethingHappens();
```

[Docs: filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)